# SQL Server Database Connection in VS 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have completed my program in MVC in VS 2010. In the connection string I have the following

```
<add name="RacePaceDBContext" 
     connectionString="data source=XX.XXX.XX.XXX,1433;Initial Catalog=RacePaceDataNew;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Which connects to a SQL Server running on an EC2 instance on Amazon AWS.

The program runs fine and the connection works great. The program connects and creates/reads data etc.

However, I am not sure why when I try "Connect To Database" in the server explorer on the left, and fill in the same settings it just doesn't connect. Any ideas why this would be different? As want to be able to log in and see my tables, data etc without having to log onto AWS. The same is true when I use MySQL Workbench to try connect - it gives me an error telling me the server isn't accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might firewall issue, Please make sure your client can connect to xx.xxx.xx.xxxx:1433.

You can also refer this : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=435146

Hope this helpful.